# Is SO now scraping my real name from my Google API?

Tags: discussion, google

I am sure I have never filled in my real name on this site, however, I have just noticed that my real name exists on my profile now.

I can only assume it was taken from my Google Auth API (which I used to login).

Now I don't mind too much so long as it ends there, I am just asking since it did not used to be on the list of permissions and I may have made the mistake of assuming that SO privileges did not change.

I consider this my fault really since I am bombarded by so many auth screens now I dain to not look at them anymore if I trust the policy holder, like Stack Exchange (how ironic).

I Google searched this a bit via "Stackoverflow real name" and "Stack exchange real name" but not much turned up.

So has SO changed its policy on information handed over?

Comment: The 'Real Name' field is private; only you and moderators can see it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah but still the information was taken, it is a question about the information being taken really.

Comment: I think it pulls your name from Facebook if you use that option, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I should probably add a time period here, i.e. I logged on earlier this week through Google and I don't think my real name was there

Comment: @Sammaye: sure, I'm just stilling a possible fear.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am bit afraid of SE using other G+ profile information

Comment: @Sammaye: see [Why do you want to "View your basic profile info"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237487) and [Why do you need to know who I know on Google?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234365)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah again my search skills fail me, the first question answer it thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Anna Lear only *new* accounts should fill the *Real Name* field from a Google Account; see [Why do you want to "View your basic profile info"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237487/why-do-you-want-to-view-your-basic-profile-info/237507#237507):

> Far as using this information goes, we currently populate the "real name" field (that isn't shown to anyone except you and the site's moderators) on new profiles with the name from the Google profile. We are also working on a feature to optionally allow folks to use the same avatar they have on Google on their SE profile at the time of signup. If they choose to switch to a different avatar at that time, we will not keep any information about their Google avatar.

Also see [Why do you need to know who I know on Google?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234365/why-do-you-need-to-know-who-i-know-on-google) where Nick assures no other info is being pulled:

> The only thing we want or use from google is your email, for communication and to associate your accounts. We don't want to know your connections or currently use that data in any way (our code isn't even aware of it).

Update: the user profile procedures for signup and editing have been updated, see [New! Smarter profile creation and syncing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239619/new-smarter-profile-creation-and-syncing). The post details how your Google info is pulled in on sign-up.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be correct. I have an "old" account, but the `real name` field was filled in automatically anyways (and this happened recently). And it does this each time I log in if the field is empty, only a dummy value prevents this.

Comment: @tim: interesting; either there is a bug in there or Anna's statement is incorrect that this only applies to new accounts.

Comment: I came here by way of Google after noticing that the newest Stack Exchange sites I had signed up for (new accounts, but still "linked" to the same GMail, not G+ account) had the info, but also my SO account, which is my oldest one. As if that wasn't bad enough, Google only knows my full name because I had to give it to use a credit card to buy stuff for my Android tablet, it's not even in my Google profile!